# filtering data stored in Couchbase

Tags: php, mysql, nosql, memcached, couchbase

I currently have a read-heavy mobile app (90% reads, 10% writes) that communicates with a single web server through php calls and single MySQL db. The db stores user profile information and messages the users send and receive.  We get a few messages per second added to the db.

I'm in the process scaling horizontally, load balancing, etc.  So we'll have a load balancer in front of a  cluster of web servers and then I plan to put a layer of Couchbase nodes on top of a MySQL cluster so we can have fast access to user profile info and messages info.  We'll memcache all user info in Couchbase but then I want to memcache only the latest 24 hours worth of messages in Couchbase since that is the timeframe where most of the read activity will happen.

For the messages data stored in memcache, I want to be able to filter messages based on various data found in a message's fields like country, city, time, etc.  I know Couchbase uses a KV approach so I can't query using where clauses like I would with MySQL.

Is there a way to do this? Is Couchbase Views the answer? Or am I totally barking up the wrong tree with Couchbase?

Answer (score 0):

The views in Couchbase Server 2.0 and later are what you're looking for.  If the data being put in Couchbase is JSON, you can use those views to perform queries across the data you put in the Couchbase cluster.

Note that you can use a view that emits a date time as an array (a common technique) and even use that in restricting your view time period so you could, potentially, just store all of your data in Couchbase without a need to put it in another system too.  If you have other reasons though, you can certainly just have the items expire 24 hours after you put them in the cache.  Then, if you're using one of the clients that supports it, you'll be able to get-and-touch the document in the cache extending the expiration if needed.  The only downside there is that you'll need to come up with a method of invalidating the document on update.

One way to do that is a trigger in mysql which would delete the given key-- another way is to invalidate it from the application layer.

p.s.: full disclosure: I'm one of the Couchbase folks